# The custom function being called on a recursive function does not call itself again. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my first time posting here since i do not want to ask on basic questions. But right now i got stuck on a bug and don't really know how to fix it.

```
const DELAY_IN_MS = 15000
const UPDATE_RATE = 100
const INDEX_LAST_PAGE = 7
const PROGRESS_BAR = document.getElementById('my-progress-bar-akram')

var slideShowTimeOut = null
var url = null
var nextPage = null
var width = 0
var currentPageNumber = 1
var progressId = null

function changeProgressBar (pctg) {
  PROGRESS_BAR.style.width = pctg + '%'
}

/**
 *
 * @param {number} pageNumber
 */
function setPage (pageNumber) {
  window.location.assign('#t'.concat(pageNumber))
}

// Progress bar
function move (mode) {
  if (mode) {
    clearInterval(progressId)
    changeProgressBar(0)
  }
  var progressId = setInterval(frame, UPDATE_RATE)
  function frame () {
    if (width < 100) {
      width = width + 100 / (DELAY_IN_MS / UPDATE_RATE)
      changeProgressBar(width)
    }
  }
}

/**
 * This is a recursive function which jumps to a next page after a delay.
 * @param {Number} page The index of the page you want to jump.
 */

function slideshow (page) {
  if(page){
    // move()
  }
  // Start the loading progress
  move()

  if (slideShowTimeOut !== null) {
    clearTimeout(slideShowTimeOut)
    changeProgressBar(0)
    clearInterval(progressId)
  }

  // Find out where we are right now
  var url = window.location.href
  if (!isNaN(page)) {
    currentPageNumber = page
  } else {
    currentPageNumber = url.slice(-1)
  }

  slideShowTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
    // Start here
    if (currentPageNumber >= INDEX_LAST_PAGE || currentPageNumber == 1) {
      setPage(2)
      // Currently in the impressum site. Stop the slideshow
    } else if (page === 'impressum') {
      clearTimeout(slideShowTimeOut)
      // Between page 2 and max page number. Set next page +1
    } else if (currentPageNumber >= 2 && currentPageNumber <= INDEX_LAST_PAGE) {
      setPage(parseInt(currentPageNumber) + 1)
    }

    slideshow()
  }, DELAY_IN_MS)
}

slideshow(1)
```

The web is already online. You can check it out here: https://cjp-hamburg.de
The idea is to jump from one "slide" to another after one specific time (DELAY_IN_MS). Furthermore, I would like to show the user to the process of this timeout as a progress bar marked by the id 'my-progress-bar-akram'.

The current problem is that the bar starts when the page is being called, but afterward it's not getting called again. So it's not recursive and I do not know why it behaves like this.

Hope there is someone here able to help me!

Regards

Akram

Comment: I cannot see a recursive function above in the code. Could you clarify which one is meant to be recursive?

Comment: Hi James! The slideshow() is a recursive function. It's getting called again after the timout :-)

Comment: Could you show that function